# Trigger definition is NULL when using Linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, linked-server

Following is the problem I am facing:-

1. When I run folllowing on ServerA, I get output

   ```
       SELECT      tbl.Name, tr.name, c.Text
       FROM      sys.sysobjects tr
             Inner Join sys.sysobjects tbl On tr.parent_obj = tbl.id
             Inner Join sys.syscomments c On tr.id = c.id
       WHERE      tr.xtype = 'TR' And tbl.xtype = 'U'
   ```
2. Problem occurs when I run same query from Server B and refer Server A as a linked server, I get no output.

   ```
       SELECT tbl.Name, tr.name, c.Text 
       FROM LinkedServerA.Database.sys.sysobjects tr
       Inner Join LinkedServerA.Database.sys.sysobjects tbl On tr.parent_obj = tbl.id
       Inner Join LinkedServerA.Database.sys.syscomments c On tr.id = c.id
       WHERE tr.xtype = 'TR' And tbl.xtype = 'U'
   ```
3. Even If I run the following I get NULL:

   Select text FROM LinkedServerA.Database.sys.syscomments

Any insight will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is your linked server setup properly? The statement works for me querying a linked server.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your login is mapped to linked server using another login, so you have no permissions to view metadata using **linked server login**.

You can check your login as well as your db user/roles on linked server using this code:

```
select * 
from openquery([YourLinkedServer], 'select system_user as linked_srvr_login, 
                             name from YourDB.sys.user_token where principal_id > 0')
```

Comment: following is the outcome of the query you asked to run        
linked_srvr_login name
linkedserverlogin linkedserverlogin
linkedserverlogin db_datareader

Comment: as you see you are not mapped to linked server with your login name, but with linkedserverlogin that is only a db_datareader. So you just have no permissions to see triggers metadata